# why Git not sync compiled files (.o and .mod files) for Fortran

Tags: git

I created a Git repository in gitlab for my fortran codes before compiling. My understanding is that git would sync any changes that happened in the local folder. However, I found that it only sync the changes to source codes, in my case, they are .F files, but the compiled files (.o and .mod files). Is this a default of Git, which only sync the source codes? Or maybe can it be changed?

Comment: Normally, you do *not* want to track changes to generated files.  Most likely, you have a rule somewhere telling git to ignore .o files.  RTFM `man gitignore`

Comment: Found it! Cuz I'm working in a team Git, someone else must have set up the ignore file. I guess the ignore file was downloaded automatically when I first time pulled the repository.@WilliamPursell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git track every file not only files with source code. You have to create a `.gitignore` file and add all files you want to ignore.

```
/*.o
/*.mod
```

for example. Most times it's better to make an output folder where you can compile your files into and ignore the complete folder.